# Passing data between components in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I've got a class component which contains a 'Switch' in react native. It currently looks like this:

colorswitch.js:

```
`export default class ColorTextSwitch extends React.Component{
    constructor(...args) {
        super(...args);
        /**
         * default state
         */
            this.state = {         
                switch: {         
                    colorTrueSwitchIsOn: true,         
                    colorFalseSwitchIsOn: false,         
                    colorBgTint: {         
                        onColor: "#29E877",         
                        offColor: "#00FFFF",         
                        thumbBtnColor: "#FFFFFF"         
                    },         
                },
            }
        }
        updateSeason(value){
            let falseSwitch = this.state.switch;
            falseSwitch.colorFalseSwitchIsOn = value;
            this.setState({ falseSwitch });
            this.props.onChange = value;
        }
        render() {
            return(
                <View style={styles.rowView} underlayColor="#e4e4e4">
                    <View style={styles.itemContentView}>
                        <Image style={styles.switchIcon} source={this.state.switch.colorFalseSwitchIsOn ? require('../assets/icon_add.png') : require('../assets/icon_minus.png')} />
                        <Text style={styles.switchText}>{this.state.switch.colorFalseSwitchIsOn ? 'SIDE1' : 'SIDE2'}</Text>
                    </View>
                    <Switch
                        onValueChange={(value) => this.updateSeason(value)}
                        onTintColor={this.state.switch.colorBgTint.offColor}
                        tintColor={this.state.switch.colorBgTint.onColor}
                        style={styles.switch}
                        thumbTintColor={this.state.switch.thumbBtnColor}
                        value={this.state.switch.colorFalseSwitchIsOn} />
                </View>
            );
        }
    }
```

`

menu.js:

```
render(){
     <ColorTextSwitch onChange={ (...args) => this.updateValue(...args) } />

...


updateValue(item){
    this.setState({itemValue: item.value});
  }
```

So what I can't wrap my head around is how the data moves from the ColorTextSwitch to the Menu, where I can use that true false value on my menu. What's teh best way to pass this data?

Comment: The data moves from `ColorTextSwitch` to the `Menu` here: `onChange={ (...args) => this.updateValue(...args) }`, you are instructing the `onChange` handler of `ColorTextSwitch` to call `Menu.updateValue` with whatever it receives - and that calls `this.setState`

Comment: @RobM. I was kinda looking for someone to point me in the right direction. I get what you're saying, it's just this code doesn't actually work.